# Display products if part of category

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a product page with 4 different category tabs on it. A created product can only belong to one of the 4 categories/tabs on the page. These categories are all displayed on the top of the tab-pane via images side-by-side. What needs to be added to the `<% @packs.each do |pack| %>` section to load the products "if" they are of that category, thank you!

This is an example of one of the tab Category selection links...

```
<a href="#samplePacks" aria-controls="samplePacks" data-toggle="tab">
  <h2 class="base-text">Samples</h2>
  <%= image_tag("btn_Category_1.png", :alt => "Category one", class: "image-pad center") %>
</a>
```

Followed by its corresponding tab, linked to the selector above...

```
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade in active" id="samplePacks">
  <div class="wellone pack-well">
    <div class="row" id="samplePillars">

      <% @packs.each do |pack| %>
        <div class="col-md-4 pack-pad">
          <%= link_to pack_path(pack) do %>
            <%= image_tag("#{pack.art_link}", :alt => "Product Image", :width => 333, :height => 333, class: "feat-img") %>
          <% end %>
        </div>
      <% end %>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My packs' DB table has a column `t.integer "category_id"`

My categories' DB table has a column `t.string "name"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up going with a different solution to this problem.

In my **packs.view** (the `&` lets the code run even when there is nothing in the db with that category):

```
<% @packs['sample-pack']&.each do |pack| %>
  <div class="col-md-4 pack-pad img-cont">
    <%= link_to pack_path(pack) do %>
      <%= image_tag("#{pack.art_link}", :alt => "", class: "img-responsive shade packit") %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

In my **packs controller**: `@packs = Pack.friendly.all.group_by(&:category_id)`

I'm using a gem called friendly_id, that's the only reason why `.friendly` is there.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it a few different ways. Here's two:

In your controller,
`@packs = @packs.group_by { |pack| pack.category.name }` *should* result in something like `{'samplePillars' => [Pack, Pack]}`

In your view

`@packs.select { |pack| pack.category.name == 'samplePillars' }.each do ... end` will return an array of `@packs` where the `category.name` is `samplePillars`

There are more idiomatic ways of doing this but for the sake of getting started, these two are fine.

Comment: both of these will execute n +1 queries

Comment: how do we know how he's not already calling `Pack.includes(:category)`

Comment: Because he is asking how to write an if condition. Although that might be a nice addition to your answer

Comment: > "What needs to be added to the `<% @packs.each do |pack| %>` "

is a pretty strong indicator of having a use-case for `Enumerable#select`

Comment: You're right, he should be using a view model or presenter for this. But since he's clearly a new developer that would likely confuse him.

Comment: I was not suggesting that your answer is wrong `Enumerable` methods are perfect for this. I was suggesting that you inform on how to preload this data rather than `pack.category` executing "SELECT categories.* FROM categories WHERE categories.id = X" pack number of times from the view context

Comment: I added `@packs = @packs.group_by { |pack| pack.category.name }` to my packs controller's `def index`... It raised this error, undefined method group_by' for nil:NilClass. Was I supposed to add this to the category controller instead? Please note, I replaced my own code of `@packs = Pack.all` with your provided code above.

Comment: @Jake try `@packs = Pack.includes(:category).group_by { |pack| pack.category.name }`

Comment: Hmm, now the .name is an undefined method error. I have the proper associations between the packs & category models, I also have this line in the packs controller, `def index` `@categories = Category.all` _the code in my question is in the packs index btw_

Comment: This could be a few things. My initial guess is that one of your `Pack` objects doesn't have a `Category` associated to it. You may have either a `nil` `category_id` or a `category_id` that doesn't relate to a `Category` (because you may have deleted it for testing, for example)

Comment: You could go backwards with the `@categories = Category.all` and do `@categories = Category.includes(:packs).all` and then iterate that way: `@category.each do |category| ... category.packs.each do |pack| ... end ... end`

Comment: I'm not quite sure if I understand how to actually load the _specific_ category with this approach. I am trying to get your initial answer to work but it's saying that `undefined method category' for "Vocal Pack":String` I also tried `category_id` but with the same error. (This does not happen when I delete all packs from the page, only when there is one present in the packs' db.)

Comment: @JoshBrody I've added a comment to my question for clarity on my db.